# Xpath - Exclude elements within TD

Tags: xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to use Chrome's scraper extension using XPath. I've been able to scrape everything I need from a table, but I'm stuck in one spot. Here's the source

```
<td>
<p class="pClass">
    <a href="theurl" target="_blank">
        <i class="iClass">someText</i>
    Anchor text
    </a>
</p>
</td>
```

I'm trying to grab just the URL, but when using my Xpath code as `td[9]/p/a` it grabs the icon part that says "someText". Is there a way to just grab the URL?

Comment: Just add `@href` to your xpath expression, this should work: `//td[9]/p/a/@href`

Comment: Thanks @vold. As you can see, complete newb here. Any chance you know how to get rid of extra white space before and after text without killing the spaces within the text?

Comment: Nevermind @vold. Figured out it's normalize-space. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to extract  url just add `@href` to your xpath expression, this should work: `//td[9]/p/a/@href`.
For stripping white space you can use xpath function [normalize-space()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256063(v=vs.110).aspx).